# python selenium - how to execute mobile chrome on incognito mode?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, mobile

I'm trying to implement mobile chrome crawler using python selenium.

And I want to execute mobile chrome on incognito mode.
So, I tried as below.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
## run chrome on incognito mode not to use web cache.
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_experimental_option('androidPackage','com.android.chrome')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

But, mobile chrome was executed on default mode, not incognito mode.
Help me please.

Comment: Do you actually manage to launch chrome on your mobile using the above code?

Comment: @EugeneS yeah. I referenced https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started/getting-started---android

Answer (score 0):

The officially recommended way to launch Chrome on mobile device using Python is this:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
                      desired_capabilities = chrome_options.to_capabilities())
```

See if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This *worked* for me:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome("driver path", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```